# Select Multiple Columns into One

Tags: sql

I want to be able to take three columns from one table and put them into a single column in another.

So I want to do this query,

```
SELECT Ref.Gender_Id,
   NHS1.Name,
   NHS2.Name,
   NHS3.Name
FROM DDS.Referrals Ref
LEFT JOIN DDS.NHSCommunicationNeed NHS1 ON NHS1.Id = REF.NHSCommunicationNeed1_Id
LEFT JOIN DDS.NHSCommunicationNeed NHS2 ON NHS2.Id = REF.NHSCommunicationNeed2_Id
LEFT JOIN DDS.NHSCommunicationNeed NHS3 ON NHS3.Id = REF.NHSCommunicationNeed3_Id
```

And insert it into a table like this

```
#Tbl(GenderId, Value)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into Tbl (GenderId, Value)

select Ref.Gender_Id,
       coalesce(NHS1.Name, '') ||  coalesce(NHS2.Name, '') ||  coalesce(NHS3.Name, '')
from ...
```

Concatenate the names. ANSI SQL uses `||`, but some products have `+` or `concat()` instead.

Use `coalesce()` to avoid null values. (ANSI SQL's concatenation returns null if one of the arguments is null.) (However, some dbms return a value anyway when concatenating with a null value, so you can perhaps skip coalesce.)

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl(Gender_Id,Value) 
SELECT Ref.Gender_Id,
  CONCAT(NHS1.Name,NHS2.Name,NHS3.Name) -- Check NOTE
FROM DDS.Referrals Ref
LEFT JOIN DDS.NHSCommunicationNeed NHS1 ON NHS1.Id = REF.NHSCommunicationNeed1_Id    
LEFT JOIN DDS.NHSCommunicationNeed NHS2 ON NHS2.Id =  REF.NHSCommunicationNeed2_Id
LEFT JOIN DDS.NHSCommunicationNeed NHS3 ON NHS3.Id = REF.NHSCommunicationNeed3_Id
```

NOTE: **`CONCAT`**(Does concatenate 2 or more columns) is handled differently in different DBMS. As you haven't mentioned the DBMS you are using, you would have to take that in account.